# Lua (5.0) equivalent of python struct.pack

Tags: python, lua

I'm trying to convert some python code to Lua.  What is the Lua equivalent to:

```
value2 = ''
key = 'cmpg'
value1 = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
Value2 += '%s%s%s' % (key, struct.pack('>i', len(value1)), value1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You said in a comment:

> I may be able to get by with knowing the string generated by each of
>   the following: struct.pack('>i',4),struct.pack('>i',8), and
>   struct.pack('>i',10)

The effector '>i' means bigendian signed 32-bit integer. For non-negative input x, the simple Python equivalent would be

`chr((x >> 24) & 255) + chr((x >> 16) & 255) + chr((x >> 8) & 255) + chr(x & 255)`

You should be able to express that in Lua without much difficulty.

You said in yet another comment:

> I ... don't understand an answer (@john machin)

chr(x) is easy to find in the docs. Lua should have such a function, perhaps even with the same name.

`i >> n` shifts i right by n bits. If i is unsigned, this is equivalent to `i // ( 2 ** n)` where `//` is Python's integer floor division.

`i & 255` is a bitwise-and which is equivalent to `i % 256`.

Lua should have both of those.

The `+` is in this case string concatenation.

Have a look at this:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> def pack_be_I(x):
...     return (
...         chr((x >> 24) & 255) +
...         chr((x >> 16) & 255) +
...         chr((x >>  8) & 255) +
...         chr(x         & 255)
...         )
...
>>> for anint in (4, 8, 10, 0x01020304, 0x04030201):
...     packed = pack_be_I(anint)
...     hexbytes = binascii.hexlify(packed)
...     print anint, repr(packed), hexbytes
...
4 '\x00\x00\x00\x04' 00000004
8 '\x00\x00\x00\x08' 00000008
10 '\x00\x00\x00\n' 0000000a
16909060 '\x01\x02\x03\x04' 01020304
67305985 '\x04\x03\x02\x01' 04030201
>>>
```

You'll notice that the required output for `10` is `'\x00\x00\x00\n'` ... note that `'\x0a'` aka `'\n'` aka `chr(10)` needs care. If you are writing this stuff to a file on Windows, you must open the file in **binary** mode (`'wb'`, not `'w'`) otherwise the run-time library will insert a carriage-return byte to conform with Windows,MS-DOS,CP/M conventions for text files.

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`struct.pack`](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/) for Lua (it is based on code of `string.pack`)? It offers the same functionality you expect. Therefore, you may run the following code:

```
local key = 'cmpg'
local value1 = '\0\0\0\0\0\1'
local packed = key .. struct.pack('>i', #value1) .. value1
```

Or, looking at the examples in the docs, you can also do it like this:

```
local packed = key .. struct.pack('>ic0', #value1, value1)
```

To unpack such string, use the following (assuming you only have `<length,string>` in `data`):

```
local unpacked = struct.unpack('>ic0', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [string.pack](http://www.luteus.biz/Download/LoriotPro_Doc/LUA/LUA_For_Windows/lpack/index.html); you can find precompiled binaries for Windows included with [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/).

```
value2 = ''
key = 'cmpg'
value1 = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
value2 = string.format("%s%s%s", key, string.pack(">i", #value1, value))
```

If you are using [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html) (which I highly recommend), you can use FFI and cast the original value to a byte array and use memcpy.

Comment: I am at the mercy of a limited implementation of Lua 5.0 within an application.  Unfortunately, string.pack is not valid. I have just requested `pack` to be added to the `string` library, but will have to wait and see if my request is granted...

Answer (score 1):

[Read Write Format](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ReadWriteFormat) wiki page contains functions that provide a way to pack / unpack integer values into a binary string.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/r9kwV)

```
-- Write an integer in MSB order using width bytes.
function numbertobytes(num, width)
  local function _n2b(t, width, num, rem)
    if width == 0 then return table.concat(t) end
    table.insert(t, 1, string.char(rem * 256))
    return _n2b(t, width-1, math.modf(num/256))
  end
  return _n2b({}, width, math.modf(num/256))
end

io.write("<", numbertobytes(0x61626364, 4), ">\n")
```

#### Output

```
<abcd>
```